# Splitting Multiple Numbers

Tags: c#, input, split, numbers

I'm just getting into learning c#, and I'm a little bit over my head. I'm trying to let a user input a list of 5 grades, and then split them to calculate the highest, lowest, and average.

I can't use int and split together, but I'm not sure how to get this to work.

Thanks!

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 Grades; Whole Integers Only, 0-100; One Space Between Grades");
int allgrades = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string[] splitgrades = allgrades.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

g1.Name = name + "'s GradeBook";
Console.WriteLine(g1.Name);

Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Calculate Gradebook Statistics");
Console.ReadKey();

GradeBook book = new GradeBook();
book.AddGrade(splitgrades[0]);
book.AddGrade(splitgrades[1]);
book.AddGrade(splitgrades[2]);
book.AddGrade(splitgrades[3]);
book.AddGrade(splitgrades[4]);
```

Thank you all for your help; I changed it around to

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 Grades; Whole Integers Only, 0-100; One Space Between Grades");
        string[] splitgrades = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int grade = int.Parse(splitgrades[0]);
        int grade1 = int.Parse(splitgrades[1]);
        int grade2 = int.Parse(splitgrades[2]);
        int grade3 = int.Parse(splitgrades[3]);
        int grade4 = int.Parse(splitgrades[4]);
```

Comment: split and then parse. you r doing reverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second line, you're trying to parse the entire input into a single `int`. You want to first split the `string` into different `int`s, then parse each separately.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the user for a space-delimited list of integers, then trying to parse that string into a single integer. That will cause much sadness during runtime. Instead, you want something like this:

```
string allGrades = Console.ReadLine();
string[] splitGrades = allGrades.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will leave you with an array of (hopefully) 5 integer grades you can add to your `GradeBook`. When doing so would be the proper time to parse integers from the individual strings in the array.

```
// Use a foreach instead to allow the user to enter as many grades as they want.
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    book.AddGrade(int.Parse(splitGrades[i]);
```